# How do I print out a calendar month in console?

Tags: java

I have an assignment for a class I'm taking in which I have to make a Java console application, and it involves asking the user for a date, parsing that date, and working out what day of the month that date starts on.  I have to then print out a calendar to look like this:

```
Calendar for September 2016
Su  Mo  Tu  We  Th  Fr  Sa
-   -   -   -   1   2   3   
4   5   6   7   8   9   10  
11  12  13  14  15  16  17  
18  19  20  21  22  23  24  
25  26  27  28  29  30  -
```

I have the date, I have the number of the day that the date starts on, (eg. Day= 1 (Monday), Day= 2(Tuesday), etc.)

Now, I can use a very messy looking switch statement with nested if statements that says, depending on the value of Day, and the number of days in that month, print out this pre-made calendar, and I can just pre-make a calendar for every eventual combination of Day and number of days in that month.  But I don't want to do that, and I can't figure out an easier way of doing it.  Has anybody got any ideas of a tidier, more succinct way of doing it?  Would it be something involving 2d arrays?

PS.  I'm not allowed to use any date-based library classes available in Java.

Comment: "I'm not allowed to use any date-based library classes available in Java." Then how do you work out the start day of a given month?

Comment: How would you know what day the month starts on without a Date library?

Comment: There is no easier way without the built-in java classes. How do you think it's implemented in the built-in java classes? You have to use your messy switch and if statements. Also, you should keep a method to check for leap year

Comment: Please show your "messy looking" code so we know what you're doing right and more importantly, what you may be doing wrong. Please try to make your question more specific as well.

Comment: I'm out of the office right now, I'll post my code in 10 mins.

Comment: You may not be allowed to use library code, but I can't see any harm in studying how the library code tackled the same problem: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/time/LocalDate.java#LocalDate.getDayOfWeek%28%29 -- if you actually want to learn, look over it to get the general idea, then put it away and try and implement your own without looking again.

Answer (score 1):

well you can use this if you change your mind

```
public static void main(String args [])
    {

        // type MM yyyy
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter month and year: MM yyyy ");
        int month = in.nextInt();
        int year = in.nextInt();
        in.close();
        // checks valid month
        try {

            if (month < 1 || month > 12)
                throw new Exception("Invalid index for month: " + month);
            printCalendarMonthYear(month, year);} 

         catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static void printCalendarMonthYear(int month, int year) {
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cal.clear();
        cal.set(year, month - 1, 1); // setting the calendar to the month and year provided as parameters 
        System.out.println("Calendar for "+ cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG,
                        Locale.US) + " " + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));//to print Calendar for month and year 
        int firstWeekdayOfMonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);//which weekday was the first in month
        int numberOfMonthDays = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); //lengh of days in a month 
        printCalendar(numberOfMonthDays, firstWeekdayOfMonth);
    }
    private static void printCalendar(int numberOfMonthDays, int firstWeekdayOfMonth) {
        int weekdayIndex = 0; 
        System.out.println("Su  MO  Tu  We  Th  Fr  Sa"); // The order of days depends on your calendar

        for (int day = 1; day < firstWeekdayOfMonth; day++) {
            System.out.print("    "); //this loop to print the first day in his correct place
            weekdayIndex++;
        }
        for (int day = 1; day <= numberOfMonthDays; day++) {

            if (day<10) // this is just for better visialising because unit number take less space of course than 2
            System.out.print(day+" ");
            else System.out.print(day); 
            weekdayIndex++;
            if (weekdayIndex == 7) {
                weekdayIndex = 0;
                System.out.println();
            } else { 
                System.out.print("  ");
            }}}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. Else it is no good for future visitors to this site. All you would be doing is spoon feeding the OP, and depriving him of the benefits of creating his own code.

Comment: OP is not allowed to use any built-in date-based classes. Yet you use `GregorianCalendar` in your answer